# R: Time stamps, Unix time and correct usage of 'strptime'

Tags: r, datetime

I have a column named `timings` of class `factor` with time stamps in the following format:

```
1/11/07 15:15
```

I applied strptime on `timings` to  generate `tStamp` as follows:

```
tStamp=strptime(timings,format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
```

i)
The corresponding entry in tStamp looks like `0007-01-11 15:15:00` now. Why has it made `2007` or `07` into `0007`? What is a correct way to generate `tStamp`?

ii) 
After generating `tStamp` correctly, how do we convert it to the Unix time Seconds. (Seconds since...1970) format?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need the lowercase `%y` for 2-digit years:

```
R> pt <- strptime("1/11/07 15:15",format="%m/%d/%y %H:%M")
R> pt
[1] "2007-01-11 15:15:00 CST"
R>
```

where CST is my local timezone.

And `as.numeric()` or `as.double()` converts to a double ...

```
R> as.numeric(pt)
[1] 1168550100
```

... which has fractional seconds if those are in the input:

```
R> options("digits.secs"=3)    # show milliseconds
R> as.numeric(Sys.time())      # convert current time
[1] 1372201674.52              # now with sub0seconds.
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit, @sgibb. I'll expand it again to show subseconds.